# How can I fade this effect into the UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func colorNavBarBackground(){ 
    if let user = self.user.data, let color = user.color1 {
        if let uiColor = UIColor(hexString: color) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.colorForNavBar(uiColor), for: .default)
        }
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage.colorForNavBar(COLORS.clear)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor  = COLORS.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: COLORS.white,
            NSFontAttributeName: FONTS.navTitle
        ]
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to fade the entire effect. However, if only the background color can be faded in, that'd be fine too.

Comment: What do you mean by fade? Show it with an alpha fade animation or some type of static gradient fade?  A picture and/or some additional information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
})
```